# Nextflow not using correct machineType in Google Batch

Tags: nextflow, google-batch

I am using  NEXTFLOW  ~  version 23.10.0
This is my gcp configuration:

gcp {

```
docker {
    enabled = true
}

params {
    sra = 'SRR9686066'  // 180KB
    mongodb_connection_string = params.mongodbConnectionString // -params-file if present
}

// https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/google.html#cloud-batch
process {
    executor = 'google-batch'
    container = params.container
    machineType = 'c2d-standard-8'
    cpus = 8
    memory = '32 GB'
}
workDir = params.workDir

// google-batch configuration options
// https://github.com/wuxi-nextcode/nextflow-public/blob/8acebee6b1482a12faadbb71897a4b7b2337f0ac/docs/google.rst#L127
google {
    project = params.project
    location = 'us-east1'
    enableRequesterPaysBuckets = false
    // batch.bootDiskSize
    // batch.cpuPlatform
    batch.spot = true
    // batch.usePrivateAddress = true
    // batch.network = params.network
    // batch.subnetwork = params.subnetwork
}
```

}

```
plugins {
    id 'nf-validation'
    id 'nf-google@1.7.3-patch1'
    id 'nf-azure'
}
```

I have specified the process to use c2d-standard-8:cpus = 8:memory = '32 GB'

When I look in the compute page I see the instance created is n2d-standard-2.

What is wrong with my config file ?